# Legend with series dash type type in Kendo chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a Kendo Dataviz chart with six series, 2 series with solid line, 2 series with dashed line and 2 series with dotted lines, i have used only two colors for series, now i want to show the legend with series dash type to differentiate the series in legend, is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Chart doesn't support this feature yet and there is no workaround for this issue.